# How to write an "if" statement based on the user's input that is a float number?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the user's input and make a conditional statement that if the user's input's float number contains 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4 then round it up if not then round it down. I understand that simply using the `round()` function this will be solved but I want to use the `math.ceil()` and `math.floor()`. I only have this much so far and I am sure this is wrong.

```
import math

while True:
    x = float(input('Type something: '))
    if x in (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4):
        math.floor(x)
        print(x)
    else:
        math.ceil(x)
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check like this:

```py
while True:
    x = float(input('Type something: '))
    if x - math.floor(x)<0.5:
        x = math.floor(x)
        print(x)
    else:
        x = math.ceil(x)
        print(x)
```

Comment: This works! Can you explain the "-" next to x? Why is it there?

Comment: that's subtracting sign. I should have put spaces to make it readeble

Comment: it is simpler to use `int(x)`, look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to redefine x, `x = math.ceil(x)`

code:

```py
import math

while True:
    x = float(input('Type something: '))
    if x-int(x) < 0.5:
        x = math.floor(x)
        print(x)
    else:
        x = math.ceil(x)
        print(x)
```